# Parse query string ordering with locale swift

Tags: swift, parsing, sorting

I am querying the database like below. However, orderbyAscending does not work properly, the accented letters are all sorted at the bottom.  Is there any way Parse sorts it by locale? Or do I have to sort in the code?  The string array is not long, about 40 words.

```
  var query = PFQuery(className: RFIstanbulDistrictsClassKey)
  query.whereKey(RFIstanbulDistrictsDistrictKey, notEqualTo: "")
  query.orderByAscending(RFIstanbulDistrictsDistrictKey)

// constants are defined as follows:
// let RFIstanbulDistrictsClassKey = "IstanbulDistricts"
// let RFIstanbulDistrictsDistrictKey = "district"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to sort the array after loading it from Parse:

```
districts.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
let query = PFQuery(className: RFIstanbulDistrictsClassKey)
query.whereKey(RFIstanbulDistrictsDistrictKey, notEqualTo: "")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
  if error == nil {

    districts = objects.map { String($0[RFIstanbulDistrictsDistrictKey] as! String) }
    districts.sort { return $0 < $1 } // sort ascending
  }
}
```